# What is Being Counted?

Tags: pr.probability

There are two urns.  One contains five white balls.  The other contains 
four white balls and one black ball.  An urn is selected at random and a ball 
in that urn is selected at random and removed.  This procedure is repeated until 
one of the urns in empty.  The probability that the black ball has not 
been selected is Binomial(10,5)/2^10.  The form of the answer suggests a counting solution.  What is being counted?

Comment: Don't understand the question. Also doesn't sound like a research level question.

Comment: I am afraid, Martin, that you don't follow the idea of MO. Please read FAQ carefully to check whether your "problems" suit this site.

Comment: See http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/474/flood-of-questions-from-an-open-problem-list/

Comment: Martin has reformulated this problem in a new question, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29807/binary-sequences-of-length-2n